# How Restart Windows Server 2003 PC use C# in windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, restart

The Server state is locked.
C# in windows service, So I try use :

```
Process.Start("shutdown -r");
```

But looks like it's not working....

Is there any good way to Restart , Shutdown,  Lock, Unlock   use C# in **windows service**?

Comment: im not really sure why its not working but try making a .bak file that contain those commands and run it in the process

Comment: @zxc, thanks , little bother but still a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what restrictions apply for a windows service to spawn a child process..
For your needs, it may be worth trying and make a difference if you call the windows APIs directly.

See which one might suit your needs from -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376883(v=vs.85).aspx

You can use http://pinvoke.net/ to find out how to declare almost any win api functions in your .net app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think maybe use API is a best choice, the pinvoke is a good stuff also.

Answer (score 1):

when I REBOOT my servers, i use `shutdown /r /t 0`

It reboots the server right then.  Use at your own risk.

Comment: Did you try use it on windows service inside?

Comment: I run it from Start -> Run.  However, even in a windows service, you can execute commands via cmd.exe using the /k switch.

Here is an example. cmd.exe /k "shutdown /r /t 0" 

You may want to elaborate more on "Server state is locked".

Comment: I mean not log in,  maybe there is some software cancel it. any way I try success on my win8. thanks.